# Android is Killing Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm currently trying to run a commnad using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` which executes a program stored on the system. This program performs some processing that takes about 20-30 seconds to finish, but for some reason when I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` the processing lasts for like 3 seconds. After that, the process seems to be killed and no return is received by my app.
Does anyone knows why is this happneing?

Thanks